# Jface: How to filter a treeviewer without blocking the UI?

Tags: java, eclipse-plugin, treeview, swt, jface

I'm new to eclipse plugin development. I'm working on an issue in which the UI blocked for long time for treeViewer filtering. In this process, Namepatterfilter is apply to the treeviewer and first few nodes are expanded programmatically to show the result. On analysing the namepattern is called only when the node is expanded. If a node has large number of children, the time taken for expanding is too long. since expanding a node runs in UI thread, the UI is blocked for other UI activities. I wonder, is there any other way of filtering without depending on the UI?. Like filtering the model, then apply it to Treeviewer?

Comment: What is your filter doing? A straightforward filter should not cause much of a slow down.

Comment: The viewer has a text box above it. The viewer filters out the items that matches the entered text.

Comment: You could perhaps look at `org.eclipse.ui.dialogs.FilteredTree` which does exactly what you describe.

Comment: Actually, I had already came across it. But the problem is mine is a navigator which extends commonViewer. Is there a possibility to change that? Because commonViewer is extending treeViewer